# Backbone Marionette Slow Composite Views (200+ collections)

Tags: backbone.js, collections, marionette

When showing a dropdown composite view collection of around 200 countries my application gets far too slow.

What is the best way to increase performance when dealing with large collections in marionette composite views?

Here is the function in the controller that is very slow to load. It is fast with only the following lines removed:

```
 @layout.shippingCountryRegion.show shippingCountryView
 @layout.billingCountryRegion.show billingCountryView
```

So it appears to be a very slow rendering issue.

```
 Show.Controller =
  showProfile: ->
    @layout = @getLayoutView()

    @layout.on "show", =>
      headerView = @getHeaderView()
      @layout.headerRegion.show headerView

      accessView = @getAccessView()
      @layout.accessRegion.show accessView

      billingReadmeView = @getBillingReadmeView()
      @layout.billingReadmeRegion.show billingReadmeView

      billingFieldsView = @getBillingFieldsView()
      @layout.billingFieldRegion.show billingFieldsView

      shippingReadmeView = @getShippingReadmeView()
      @layout.shippingReadmeRegion.show shippingReadmeView

      shippingFieldsView = @getShippingFieldsView()
      @layout.shippingFieldRegion.show shippingFieldsView

      MyApp.request "location:get_countries", (countries) =>
        billingCountryView = @getBillingCountryView(countries)
        @layout.billingCountryRegion.show billingCountryView

      MyApp.request "location:get_states", MyApp.activeCustomer.get('billing_country_id'), (states) =>
        billingStateView = @getBillingStatesView(states)
        @layout.billingStateRegion.show billingStateView

      MyApp.request "location:get_countries", (countries) =>
        shippingCountryView = @getShippingCountryView(countries)
         @layout.shippingCountryRegion.show shippingCountryView

      MyApp.request "location:get_states", MyApp.activeCustomer.get('shipping_country_id'), (states) =>
        shippingStateView = @getShippingStatesView(states)
        @layout.shippingStateRegion.show shippingStateView

    MyApp.mainRegion.show @layout
```

The billing country view:

```
class View.BillingCountryDropdownItem extends MyApp.Views.ItemView
  template: billingCountryItemTpl
  tagName: "option"

  onRender: ->
    this.$el.attr('value', this.model.get('id'));
    if MyApp.activeCustomer.get('billing_country_id') == this.model.get('id')
      this.$el.attr('selected', 'selected');

class View.BillingCountryDropdown extends MyApp.Views.CompositeView
  template: billingCountryTpl
  itemView: View.BillingCountryDropdownItem
  itemViewContainer: "select"
```

The template, simply:

```
        <label>Country
        <select id="billing_country_id" name="billing_country_id">
           <%- name %>
        </select>
    </label>
```

Comment: Why are you setting model's value from `onRender` method ?

Comment: And what is <%- name %> inside composite template?

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be optimized. Just move content of `onRender` method to the `ItemView` attributes.

```
class View.BillingCountryDropdownItem extends MyApp.Views.ItemView
  template: billingCountryItemTpl
  tagName: "option"

  attributes: -> 
    var id = this.model.get('id'); 
    var attributes = { 'value': id };
    if MyApp.activeCustomer.get('billing_country_id') == this.model.get('id')
      attributes['selected'] =  'selected';
    return attributes
```

---

The difference between this method and `onRender` case is that, on render will execute when collection already rendered and 200+ operations will be done with DOM nodes, which will bring performance issues.

In case of `attributes` method, it executes upon view creation.

Answer (score 0):

There are few advices you can follow:

1) Ask your self do you really need to render all items at once? Maybe you can render part of collection and render other items on scroll or use pagination or use 'virtual scrioll' with [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)  or [Webix](http://webix.com/blog/webix-grid-1-000-000-rows-and-more/) for example.

2) Checkout how often you re-render your view. Try to minify num of events cause re-render

3) Try to minify num of event listeners of ItemView. Its good practice to delegate context events to CollectionView

4) You can use `setTimeout` to render collection by parts. For example you divide you coll in 4 parts by 50 items and raise 4 timeouts to render it.

5) You can optimize underscore templating and get rid of `with {}` operator. http://underscorejs.org/#template

Answer (score 0):

What's in your 'billingCountryItemTpl' varible? If it's just string with template ID then you could precompile your template using [Marionette.TemplateCache](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.templatecache.md).

So you'll have:

```
template: Marionette.TemplateCache.get(billingCountryItemTpl)
```